# Почему не изменяется стиль виджета PyQT5?

Tags: python, sqlite

Работаю с кодом на Python и SQLite. Стиль для виджета должен выгружаться из базы данных и ставиться на виджет, однако этого не происходит. Стиль выгружается корректно, значит, проблема не с базой данных. Можно ли как-то исправить это?

```
def unload(self):
cur = self.con.cursor()
rezult = cur.execute('''SELECT DISTINCT Название, label, Текст, Статус, LCD, Время, kol, kol_1, kol_2 FROM Задачи
                        WHERE Дата LIKE ?''', (str(self.date),))
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    exec('{}.setStyleSheet('.format(row[0]) + '"""{}""")'.format(row[3]))
```

Comment: Выведите `'{}.setStyleSheet('.format(row[0]) + '"""{}""")'.format(row[3])` в `print` и добавьте результат в вопрос

Comment: Результат: self.widget_1.setStyleSheet("""border-radius: 10px;

        color: white;

        background-color:rgb(8, 170, 73);""")

Comment: Выглядит правдоподобно. Повторил код с `exec` на своем примере и у указанной в `row[0]` кнопки стиль поменялся. Предоставьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) с этой проблемой